# Debate on GET vs POST with RESTful Service

Tags: http, rest, http-post, http-get

So I have an ajax call that calls a controller action that fires off a package for execution that is separate from my main application which returns a result. That result (a success or failure) is what I want returned from that controller action and the ajax action is currently a GET request with the parameters for the package being sent with the request. Should this be a GET request to be 'RESTful', or should it be a POST request?

Comment: If it were a long-running process, you might use POST to start a distributed process, and GET to get the state of the process as it runs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would say it should be a POST. GET should have no other effects then to retrieve a representation of data. [Here's](http://www.w3.org/2001/tag/doc/whenToUseGet.html#checklist) what W3C says.

Use GET if:

- The interaction is more like a question (i.e., it is a safe operation such as a query, read operation, or lookup).

Use POST if:

- The interaction is more like an order, or
- The interaction changes the state of the resource in a way that the user would perceive (e.g., a subscription to a service), or
- The user be held accountable for the results of the interaction.

Comment: Good post. In support the HTML spec calls out post as the operation for "data processing" requests, which pretty much fits the bill here.

Comment: Well, what's relevant is the *HTTP* spec (and that's an *IETF* spec, not a W3C spec).